# Django - data too large for session

Tags: django, session, django-queryset

I have a view in which I query the database then I give the queryset to session and use it in other views. It works fine most of the time but in vary rare cases when the queryset gets very large, it takes a long time and I get a timeout. What I would like to know is if I am doing the right thing? If not, what is the best practice for this case? What options do I have?

Comment: We would need more information to give you an intelligent answer. Why is your workflow structured this way? What code are you using to grab and pass this data around? There could be a much better way to accomplish things in your case, but we don't know enough about what your case *is* to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **never** store QuerySet data in sessions. You need just to make a list (like [1,2,3,4,5]) of all id's you need, then send it.

Next step it is to get QuerySet from list of id's:

```
data_list = request.session['data_list']
services = Service.objects.filter(id__in=data_list)
```

and now you have same QuerySet you have before, but sessions never be filled.